# OCR fields recognition

Tags: ocr

can somebody help me with next question, we need use OCR technology but we don't need all text, only some fields from invoices and receips, can't find what is better solution for this

Comment: Could you add some code of what you've done yet, some more context or examples?

Comment: The problem is which technology is better to use

Comment: This depends a lot on your problem and comes with lots of other questions. You need to bring more _technical_ details on the question. Stackoverflow won't simply develop an app for you from scratch

Comment: I didn't ask simply develop an app for me from scratch, the question was which tecnology can make field recognition

Comment: What kind of input are you using?  pictures? pdf? online-screen-capture? 
Is this a web-based app? a mobile app?  
What language is the code in?

Comment: Pictures, jpeg or png, we tried connect google vision api but didn't find possibilities to recognize field, it gives all text from document

Comment: And are those pictures always formatted in the same way? (i.e. are the field you're looking for roughly in the same places in the pictures?) Are the receipts /invoices always from the same company? (What I'm asking is basically : could you draw a rectangle on the picture which would capture the info you're looking for? and if so, is it always at the same place? )

Comment: Actually pictures always formatted in the same way, they are not from the same company, but yes, those fields are at the same place on a documents

Comment: Alright! Moving forward!
You could use vision library (like opencv: https://opencv.org/ ) to implement some automated "smaller image" extraction.  With this you could automatically fetch some sections of the pictures, and then feed them to the googlevision api again...
Technically this could also be a candidate for DeepLearning and convolutionDNN, but that's a deep dive.
And those are two possible way you could do such a thing, but they're not the only ones...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start mobile app development, you can use the Text Recognition Service, at the core of which is OCR technology. For example, [Huawei ML Kit Text recognition API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/text-recognition-0000001050040053#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050750207__section16220018134717?ha_source=hms1), [Google Firebase ML's text recognition API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text), etc. You can extract the required text information(invoices and receipts if you need) ) through code.

I will list main procedures for ML Kit Text recognition integration, you can also download the demo on [Github](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ml-demo/tree/master/ApplicationCases/Receipt-Text-Recognition).

1. **Preparations**

1). **Configure the Maven Repository Address in the Project-Level build.gradle File**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
     ...
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}
 dependencies {
   ...
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
     ...
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
}
```

2). **Add Configurations to the File Header**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

3). **Configure SDK Dependencies in the App-Level build.gradle File**

```
dependencies {
    // Import the base SDK.
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr:2.0.1.300'
    // Import the Latin character recognition model package.
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr-latin-model:2.0.1.300'
    // Import the Japanese and Korean character recognition model package.
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr-jk-model:2.0.1.300'
    // Import the Chinese and English character recognition model package.
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr-cn-model:2.0.1.300'
}
```

4). **Add these Statements to the AndroidManifest.xml File so the Machine Learning Model can Automatically Update**

```
<manifest>
 ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.huawei.hms.ml.DEPENDENCY"
        android:value="ocr" />
     ...
</manifest>
```

5). **Apply for the Camera Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

**2. Code Development**

1). **Create an Analyzer**

```
MLTextAnalyzer analyzer = new MLTextAnalyzer.Factory(context).setLanguage(type).create();
```

2). **Set the Recognition Result Processor to Bind with the Analyzer**

```
analyzer.setTransactor(new OcrDetectorProcessor());
```

3). **Call the Synchronous API**

Use the built-in LensEngine of the SDK to create an object, register the analyzer, and initialize camera parameters.

```
lensEngine = new LensEngine.Creator(context, analyzer)
  .setLensType(LensEngine.BACK_LENS)
  .applyDisplayDimension(width, height)
  .applyFps(30.0f)
  .enableAutomaticFocus(true)
  .create();
```

4). **Call the run Method to Start the Camera and Read the Camera Streams for the Recognition**

```
try {lensEngine.run(holder);} catch (IOException e) {// Exception handling logic.Log.e("TAG", "e=" + e.getMessage());}
```

5). **Process the Recognition Result As Required**

```
public class OcrDetectorProcessor implements MLAnalyzer.MLTransactor<MLText.Block> {
    @Override
    public void transactResult(MLAnalyzer.Result<MLText.Block> results) {
        SparseArray<MLText.Block> items = results.getAnalyseList();
        // Process the recognition result as required. Only the detection results are processed.
        // Other detection-related APIs provided by ML Kit cannot be called.
        …
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Callback method used to release resources when the detection ends.
    }
}
```

6). **Stop the Analyzer and Release the Detection Resources When the Detection Ends**

```
if (analyzer != null) {
    try {
        analyzer.stop();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception handling.
    }
}
if (lensEngine != null) {
    lensEngine.release();
}
```

You can also refer to this medium article [here](https://medium.com/huawei-developers/implement-the-automatic-bill-number-input-function-using-ml-kits-text-recognition-8a6207aa9284).

For more, see [official documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ml-text-intro-4?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of solutions that I am aware of from the LEADTOOLS SDK. Both the Master Form editor and the Document Analyzer sound like they could be useful to your use case. In the interest of full discloser, it is the company that I work for, but I would be remiss not mention it as a possible solution for your scenario.

This is a link to a YouTube video describing how the Master Forms Editor technology works.
https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo6TGcdrtb4

It essentially allows you to define pre-set zones on various forms, and then compare the document to the forms in the repository. Then it will extract the data from those zones and you can manage the OCR'd data however you would like.

As well as a link to Online Documentation that shows the coded implementation of some of the functionality:
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/to/steps-to-generate-a-master-form-and-save-it-to-a-master-repository.html

Here is a link to the other functionality that I mentioned - Document Analyzer - that one of my colleagues goes over in the Microsoft Build Post Show.
https://www.leadtools.com/blog/general/microsoft-build-post-show-v21-document-analyzer-demo/

The code for these examples, and the technology used, can be found in a 60-day free trial offer that can be downloaded from the LEAD site if you are interested in checking it out.
https://www.leadtools.com/downloads

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format your post.